# Error: Problem: conflicting requests - nothing provides /usr/bin/python needed by python-chardet in CentOS 8

Tags: python-2.7, path, rpm, centos8

I am using CentOS 8 and want to download a library for Python2.

CentOS 8 has Python3 and its libraries installed by default.

I want to download **python-chardet** library for Python2. So I tried to install it as below -

> $ sudo yum install python-chardet

I got this error -

```
No match for argument: python-chardet
Error: Unable to find a match: python-chardet
```

I searched for solution and as per this document you have to download its RPM binary and install it. https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/python-chardet-2.2.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm.html

Downloading the binary file -

> $ wget    http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/python-chardet-2.2.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm

Using this rpm library I tried to install python-chardet as below -

> $ sudo yum install ./python-chardet-2.2.1-3.el7.noarch.rpm

Here I got an error like this -

```
Error:
 Problem:  conflicting requests
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python needed by python-chardet-2.2.1-3.el7.noarch
```

Python version is

> $ python -V
>
> $ Python 2.7.16

**/usr/bin/python** returned this

> Python 2.7.16 (default, Nov 17 2019, 00:07:27)
>
> GCC 8.3.1 (RedHat) on linux2

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS/RHEL 8 doesn't have any user-facing Python installed by default.

It has Python 3 installed for system apps like `dnf`, but to use it as a user, you need `sudo dnf install python3`.

Similarly, Python 2 and everything for it can be installed by using the appropriate package name suffix. To install Python 2 and the module you need:

```
sudo dnf install python2 python2-chardet
```

The recommendation/default is that the unversioned `python` command should not work and you should invoke the desired Python version on the shell by typing `python2` instead of `python`.

If, for whatever reason you need unversioned `python` command to invoke Python 2, use the alternatives system:

```
sudo alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2
```

Comment: python2-chardet can be installed as you said but i need to specifically install python-chardet library in CentOS 8..

Comment: As I have explained, it is the same thing. With suffix

Comment: I read this over 2x and still can't get python-chardet installed. Are you suggesting to change the alternate python from 2 to 3? Neither work to allow python-chardet to install for me.

Comment: @dny238 did you manage to solve this? I am encountering the same error

Comment: Have same problem , changing the alternative didn t fix it , did you manage how to install it ?

Comment: @firasKoubaa as it was explained, you won't have any luck installing `python-chardet` because the equivalent package name in CentOS 8 is python*2*-chardet. Why do you insist on installing it with the obsolete name `python-chardet` and not with the correct `python2-chardet`?

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that python is installed, so you can see:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

you can use the following workaround: download and installing the package like this:

```
rpm -ivh your-packaege.rpm --nodeps
```